# Foreach seguido de outro Foreach na mesma linha

Tags: php, loop

É correto usar um foreach seguido do outro foreach (como no exemplo abaixo)?

```
<?php if($nome1):

    foreach ($nome1 as $nome2) foreach ($nome2->nome3() as $nome4):
?>

#code html

<?php

    endforeach;

else:

?> etc...
```

Comment: Assim, dá pra usar um foreach dentro de outro foreach, como tu postou no teu código não vejo como pode funcionar. Acredito que teria que ser assim: `foreach($array_1 as $val){ foreach($array_2 as $val) {  } }`

Comment: Olá Edward. Acredite, funciona! Mesmo quebrando a linha e jogando um Foreach para baixo do outro. Só não sei se é correto usar dessa forma pois me preocupo com boas práticas.

Comment: A lei do PHP diz: Se funcionou, só vai! kkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Não sei se está certa essa sintaxe. Você deveria usar `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível, a sintaxe é válida, não tem um correto ou errado, então pode usar se é isso que quer fazer.

Assim como em C, no PHP é possível omitir as chaves quando for definir um bloco lógico, isso tanto em condicionais quanto em laços de repetição.

Por exemplo, em

```php
if (condition) {
    a;
    b;
}
```

Tanto as expressões `a` quanto `b` estão no bloco lógico da condicional e serão avaliadas apenas quando a condição for verdadeira.

Já em

```php
if (condition)
    a;
    b;
```

Apenas a expressão `a` faz parte do bloco lógico, enquanto `b` não; isso implica que `b` será avaliado independente da condição - e poderia ser reescrito, para facilitar o entendimento, como:

```php
if (condition)
    a;
b;
```

O mesmo acontece com o `foreach`. Quando você omite as chaves, apenas a primeira expressão após a instrução fará parte do bloco lógico. Por *sorte*, outro `foreach` é considerado como uma expressão apenas até a ocorrência do `endforeach` ou das chaves, se esse possuir.

Portanto, fazer:

```php
foreach ($nome1 as $nome2) foreach ($nome2->nome3() as $nome4):
```

É o equivalente a fazer:

```php
foreach ($nome1 as $nome2)
    foreach ($nome2->nome3() as $nome4):
        ...
    endforeach;
```

Que é o mesmo que:

```php
foreach ($nome1 as $nome2) {
    foreach ($nome2->nome3() as $nome4) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Se é isso que precisa, então sim, está correto.